# Getting nil when adding urlpath to NSUrl in Swift Programming

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift

mapServerRequest="Midtown, New York, NY, USA"

```
var mapAddress:NSString=mapServerRequest

     println(mapAddress)
var urlpath=NSString(format: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@", mapAddress)
     println(urlpath)
var url = NSURL.URLWithString(urlpath)
    println(url)
```

Comment: You should encode the spaces in the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should URL encode your mapAddress:

```
mapAddress.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Comment: Thaku It's Working @cornelius